# How to send emails from the core app without coupling it to web interface

Tags: elixir, phoenix-framework

Let's say that I have two separate apps under umbrella, one is the core Elixir app which handles all the business logic and whatnot, and one is a web interface ( `Phoenix framework`, obviously ) for this core app.

So this core application should be able to send emails because it knows when and where to send them but the problem is that emails obviously contain HTML code and it would be easier to render them on the phoenix side (especially considering that I use `phoenix_swoosh` package for `swoosh` which makes it easy) than in the core app but I don't want to call the web interface's code from the core app since it breaks the boundary ( as far as I see it ) and I don't want to add phoenix as a dependency to the core app only for rendering emails either.

So the question is, what would be a good way to solve this problem? How to send emails from the core app without breaking the boundary but preferably using web interface's rendering engine? Does it make sense to maybe create some kind of event system in the core app and then just subscribe to it in the phoenix app and actually send emails from the phoenix app?

Thank you in advance. If my question is not too understandable, please let me know :)

Comment: How are you currently deciding to send emails? Does your phoenix send a message to something in the core that sends it?

Comment: @JustinWood Well, first I was just passing the functions for sending emails from the phoenix to the core and just called them there but this approach failed.

Comment: Why not just send the core whatever information it needs to process, and send the email in Phoenix based on the return value?

Comment: @JustinWood It's not that easy. Let's say I have a worker process in the core that checks some posted comments and removes them if they are 5 minutes old ( just a fake scenario but I have something similar ) and after the comment is removed, it needs to send the comment's owner an email. In this case, phoenix doesn't know anything about this worker, so no return values or anything but the worker still needs to send emails ...

Comment: Maybe it would be useful to use something like `GenEvent` or `GenStage`. You would be able to have something that generates events in core, and do something about them in your phoenix application.

Comment: @JustinWood That's the best idea I have come up with yet

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all, it depends on how you have your dependencies setup between the two projects. I will presume you have the the main app included as a dependency in your web app. This makes it difficult to call APIs in the web app from your main app.

Personally, I would setup a named GenServer in the web app. It would have a pretty simple API like `{:send, %{name: "...", email: "...", body: "..."}}`. You could have a simple API module in the main app like:

```
defmodule MyApp.Mailer do
  def send(name, email, body) do
    GenServer.cast :mail_server, {:send, %{name: name, email: email, body: body}}
  end
end
```

You could even pull this and other shared code into a separate app that can be shared between the main app and the web app.

By using a GenServer to handle the mailing, it makes it asynchronous, which is probably a good thing, unless you want the error handling. You can also make it synchronous by using `GenServer.call` instead of `GenServer.cast`.

That is probably how I would do it.

Another option could be to create a separate app for the swoosh mailer. If you did not want the weight of another phoenix instance, you could use `swoosh` alone instead of `swoosh_phoenix`. You can still use `EEx` module directly to render templates. You just miss out on the Views. However, I find that in most of my apps, I'm only using one email view anyway. So phoenix is kind of overkill.